# How can I extract the Workday job post link with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping, workday-api

I am new to Python and web scraping. Recently, I am stuck by Workday's job post links generation pattern. Normally, I found one job post's link pattern is like the following that all the elements can be extracted: (text in bold is fixed)

> https://employer's domain.com/**en-US**/employers'subtext/**job**/location/job title_job ID

For example, UPenn's Workday main page is:

> https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn

and take this job post:

> Program Coordinator for Community Care,
> JR00035938   |   VPUL   |   Posted Yesterday

As so, to compose this job post's link should be like the follows:

https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruting/upenn/careers-at-penn/job/VPUL/Program-Coordinnator-for-Community-Care_JR00035938

And the correct one from the website is as follows:

https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn/job/VPUL/Program-Coordinator-for-Community-Care_JR00035938-1

As you can see, the element shown on the page(aka, the HTML source code **scraped** by Python) is different, though the pattern is correct.
From the source from the Chrome inspect, the job id is JR00035938 without the extra "-1".

```
 <span class="gwt-InlineLabel WEAG WD5F" title="JR00035938   |   VPUL   |   Posted Yesterday" id="gwt-uid-106" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">JR00035938   |   VPUL   |   Posted Yesterday</span>
```

And this is not the only one odd, there are many differences.
Here are couples of examples:

1)

> Research Specialist A/B (Pennsylvania Muscle Institute) JR00035941
> |   Clinical Research Building - 7th Floor   |   Posted Yesterday

its code:

```
<div class="gwt-Label WCCP WLAP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-99" data-automation-label="Research Specialist A/B (Pennsylvania Muscle Institute)" title="Research Specialist A/B (Pennsylvania Muscle Institute)" aria-label="Research Specialist A/B (Pennsylvania Muscle Institute)" role="link" tabindex="0">Research Specialist A/B (Pennsylvania Muscle Institute)</div>
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel WEAG WD5F" title="JR00035941   |   Clinical Research Building - 7th Floor   |   Posted Yesterday" id="gwt-uid-100" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">JR00035941   |   Clinical Research Building - 7th Floor   |   Posted Yesterday</span>
```

And its link not only with extra subfix after job ID, but also lacks/rewrites the part after the slash of the job title.

> https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn/job/Clinical-Research-Building---7th-Floor/Research-Specialist-A--Physiology-_JR00035941-1

2. 

> Research Investigator/Research Investigator Sr. (Dept. of Radiology)
> JR00033660   |   HUP   |   Posted Yesterday

its code:

```
<div class="gwt-Label WCCP WLAP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-107" data-automation-label="Research Investigator/Research Investigator Sr. (Dept. of Radiology)" title="Research Investigator/Research Investigator Sr. (Dept. of Radiology)" aria-label="Research Investigator/Research Investigator Sr. (Dept. of Radiology)" role="link" tabindex="0">
Research 
<span class=" WHK2 WIK2 ">Investigator/Research</span> 
Investigator Sr. (Dept. of Radiology)
</div>
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel WEAG WD5F" title="JR00033660   |   HUP   |   Posted Yesterday" id="gwt-uid-108" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">JR00033660   |   HUP   |   Posted Yesterday</span>
```

And its link:

> https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn/job/HUP/Research-Investigator-Sr--Dept-of-Radiology-_JR00033660-1

At last, here comes my question, what pattern does Workday generate its job post's link? Is there any method to get its link while Workday obviously prevents others to extract the data? There is no a/href/src for the job post link.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `recruiting` - I am assuming you made a typo in your _should be like_ example.

Comment: @QHarr LOL, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are added dynamically from a GET request so you could always just grab the links that way rather than worry about trying to replicate the pattern.

```
import requests

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept': 'application/json,application/xml'}

r = requests.get('https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn', headers=headers)
links = ['https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com' + i['title']['commandLink'] for i in r.json()['body']['children'][0]['children'][0]['listItems']]
print(links)
```

Comment: I don't understand how the JSON creates links dynamically based on your answer.(The two ['children'][0]). Would you mind providing me more info/detail/links for this so that I can look into it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The json doesn't create the links. The links are retrieved from the server and delivered within the json. The json is mapped to webpage in a set of instructions you can partly see in the page source. Server side I suspect there is possibly a regex substitution method used to generate the links.

Comment: Sorry for asking silly questions, again. I was thinking, if a website like Workday that the HTML source code didn’t contain any link tags or attributes, does that mean they use JSON method to generate dynamic links? And if I want to get those links that are visible on the UI only, I should highly probably to look at its .get() JSON file?

Comment: The page is a dynamic page meaning the browser makes additional XHR requests to update the page. One of those requests gets content that includes the links and that is mapped to the appropriate location. You can view a lot of the mapping info within the returned json (see the facet info).

Comment: I have work shortly but it should be possible to work out the mapping to the page. I don't have time currently and not sure if that adds value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! However, I now encounter another problem. While I am using Selenium and BeautifulSoup to find a specific job title, the GET request of the JSON file seems didn't direct/indirect to the parsed soup. Is there any other way to get the link after soup.find_all()?